# enum method returning a dynamic type

Tags: swift, enums

I have an enum and I'd like to create a method to return a different type for every case.

For example, I have a dictionary `[String: Any]`. To process the values I'm using the enum to create an array of keys:

```
enum Foo {
    case option1
    case option2

    func createKey() -> [String] {
        switch self {
        case .option1: return ["scenario1"]
        case .option2: return ["scenario2"]
        }
    }
}
```

Once I have the values, I need to cast them to a the proper type to be able to use them. Right now I'm doing it manually using `if-statements` but it would reduce a lot of code if I can somehow create a method in the enum to return the proper type. My current code:

```
let origin: [String: Any] = ["scenario2": "someText"]
let option: Foo = .option2

option.createKey().forEach {
    guard let rawValue = origin[$0] else { return }

    switch option {
    case .option1:
        guard let value = rawValue as? Int else { return }
        print("Value is an Int:", value)
    case .option2:
        guard let value = rawValue as? String else { return }
        print("Value is a String:", value)
    }
}
```

What I would like to achieve is something like:

```
option.createKey().forEach {
    guard let rawValue = origin[$0] as? option.getType() else { return }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: But then what should `rawValue` be statically typed as? The type that your hypothetical `option.getType()` method returns isn't known until runtime.

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with the enum. What varies in your cases is Int and String.

Comment: @Hamish: the `rawValue` in my original enum is a `String`, used for other purpsoses.

Comment: @matt: The enum in the example is just a simplified version, but just like Hamish said, the type is unknown until runtime. I probably should delete the question..

Comment: But my point is, if you throw away the enum and just think about whether you are allowed to say `if let x = y as? someTypeContainedInAVariable` you will see immediately that your entire proposition falls to the ground. Swift has static typing.

Comment: @matt: I'm not entirely sure if I'm getting your point, but in my real code I have to cast it to `Int`, `Double`, and `Decimal` (and several others). The source value can be a `NSNumber` so all 3 of them would succeed. If I'm totally missing your point, then sorry.

Comment: The point is, what would be returned by `option.getType`? It would be a type. But you cannot say `if let x = y as? someTypeContainedInAVariable` where `someTypeContainedInAVariable` is a variable containing a type, or a function call returning a type. It has to be a literal type right there in the line!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the core of the problem here is that Swift has strict typing. That means types must be known at compile time. This, obviously, is legal:

```
let s : Any = "howdy"
if let ss = s as? String {
    print(ss)
}
```

But this is not legal:

```
let s : Any = "howdy"
let someType = String.self
if let ss = s as? someType { // *
    print(ss)
}
```

`someType` must be a *type*; it cannot be a variable hiding a type inside itself. But that is precisely what, in effect, you are asking to do.

Comment: Ok, understood. Thanks for the great explanation! Too bad, it would have made my code looks a bit more clean.